# Katalon studio - How to write into different columns of excel with different loops

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ui-automation, katalon-studio

I have the following code in my

```
@Keyword 
public void demoKey(String variable1,int index1) throws IOException{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Selenium\\PortalRedesigNLogic.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(index1);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(variable1);
//  sheet.getRow(index1);
//  row.getCell(1);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Selenium\\PortalRedesigNLogic.xlsx");
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

this writes fine for one column but then I have another loop in a CALL test case
and I want this same keyword to loop through and write in the second column
so I can compare the data from both loops
the first column and second column.

My test case looks like this:

```
 CustomKeywords.'common.WriteToExcelrow1.demoKey'(x, sitedropdownloop)
```

x (is the innertext that will be written in) and sitedropdownloop is the loop name

also in the CALL test case, I have

```
CustomKeywords.'common.WriteToExcelrow1.demoKey'(y, oldsitedropdownloop)
```

y ( is the innertext that will be written in the second column) and oldsitedropdownloop is the name of the other loop.

Comment: `Cell cell = row.createCell(0);` creates a cell in the 1st column, `Cell cell = row.createCell(1);` would create a cell in the 2nd column

Comment: I do understand that, but since the loop is in another call test case should i use another keyword. I have acctually went that route and created another keyword with createCell(1) but the issue is when i run it .. all the data that is created on cell(0) gets deleted and the new data gets created in Cell(2) ... i want both data  to be there ....

Comment: So, what actually happens when you run the test cases?

Comment: Hi what happens is if i have the same common.write.toexcelrow1.demokey for both loops  the data gets added in excel, but then when the other loop starts , the first data gets deleted and the new data is added in excel , now if i have two different  keywords,  same thing is happening ....